# T-SQL query one table, get presence or absence of other table value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm not sure what this type of query is called so I've been unable to search for it properly. I've got two tables, Table A has about 10,000 rows. Table B has a variable amount of rows.

I want to write a query that gets all of Table A's results but with an added column, the value of that column is a boolean that says whether the result also appears in Table B.

I've written this query which works but is slow, it doesn't use a boolean but rather a count that will be either zero or one. Any suggested improvements are gratefully accepted:

```
SELECT u.number,u.name,u.deliveryaddress, 
            (SELECT COUNT(productUserid) 
             FROM ProductUser 
             WHERE number = u.number and productid = @ProductId) 
             AS IsInPromo

FROM Users u
```

**UPDATE**

I've run the query with actual execution plan enabled, I'm not sure how to show the results but various costs are:

Nested Loops (left semi join): 29%]

Clustered Index scan (User Table): 41%

Clustered Index Scan (ProductUser table): 29%

**NUMBERS**
There are 7366 users in the users table and currently 18 rows in the productUser table (although this will change and could be in the thousands)

Comment: How many rows are in `Users` and how many in `ProductUser`? And what is the result of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProductUser WHERE productid = @ProductId`? A scan on the inside of a NL join is not good `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix on ProductUser(productid,number)` will probably give you a plan with a NL and index seek or maybe a merge join if suitable index on `Users `

Comment: 2 seconds seems long for 7366 users in the users table and currently 18 rows in the productUser table.  Review the indexes and defrag.  What is the order of the PK on productUser.  Try flopping the order and both the exists and join options.  Do you have the FK defined?  Try hints on the join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to short circuit after the first row is found rather than `COUNT`-ing all matching rows.

SQL Server does not have a boolean datatype. The closest equivalent is `BIT`

```
SELECT u.number,
       u.name,
       u.deliveryaddress,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM   ProductUser
                      WHERE  number = u.number
                             AND productid = @ProductId) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
         ELSE  CAST(0 AS BIT)
       END AS IsInPromo
FROM   Users u
```

RE: "I'm not sure what this type of query is called". This will give a plan with a semi join. See [Subqueries in CASE Expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/23/715306.aspx) for more about this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, just tried this and it works but takes a similar length of time to run as my version. Is there anything I can do to optimise it? Also, thanks for letting me know what it's called, hard to google for something when you don't know the name for it!

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton - You would need to show us the plan you get. You are likely missing a useful index.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton - Please script out the `CREATE TABLE` for `Users` and `ProductUser` and include it into your question (including indexes). Also run the query with the "Include Actual Execution Plan" option enabled in SSMS and show us the plan.

Comment: Have updated the question with the Actual Execution Plan enabled. Not sure how to display the info. All variants of this query seem to take roughly 2 seconds to run, maybe that's the best I can hope for.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton - You still haven't told us what indexes you already have. I'm going offline now anyway but have suggested an index that will probably help. If not please supply the information requested. Best way of supplying the plan is to upload the XML for the actual execution plan (not estimated) to a hosting service such as pastebin.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Martin, appreciated. I will try your suggested index and will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton - Though I just saw your update about number of rows. That is pretty small. `7366 * 18 = 132,588` rows. I would have expected even the nested loops plan with the repeated scan of the 18 rows to take much less than 2 seconds. Is there any concurrent activity on the database? Maybe you are encountering some blocking from concurrent transactions. Also are you running this query locally or over a network?

Comment: Yes agreed, that's what's strange about it. In any case I've added the suggested index. No difference I'm afraid but that's possibly the best I can hope for from this query. No blocking, it's just me running a query on this but it is over a network.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton - In one connection in SSMS run that query in a loop. `WHILE (1=1) BEGIN <query_goes_here> END` And in another whilst the loop is running try `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks WHERE session_id > 50`  a few times and see what wait types you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Which management system are you using?
Try this:

```
SELECT u.number,u.name,u.deliveryaddress, 
            case when COUNT(p.productUserid) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
FROM Users u
left join ProductUser p on p.number = u.number and productid = @ProductId
group by u.number,u.name,u.deliveryaddress
```

UPD: this could be faster using mssql

```
;with fff as
(
    select distinct p.number  from ProductUser p where p.productid = @ProductId
)
select u.number,u.name,u.deliveryaddress,  
    case when isnull(f.number, 0) = 0 then 0 else 1 end 
from Users u left join fff f on f.number = u.number
```

Comment: Takes 2 seconds to run, same as the other queries I'm afraid.

Comment: You have too small amount of rows in ProductUser then, to see an impact.

Comment: CTE is just syntax. That expression evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

Since you seem concerned about performance, this query can perform faster as this will cause `index seek` on both tables versus an `index scan`:

```
SELECT u.number,
       u.name,
       u.deliveryaddress,       
       ISNULL(p.number, 0)  IsInPromo
FROM   Users u 
       LEFT JOIN ProductUser p ON p.number = u.number
WHERE   p.productid = @ProductId
```

Comment: Seriously why a down vote? We need to help the OP with performance ("works but is slow") and the query gives the right result?

Comment: -1 The performance claim is incorrect and the `WHERE  p.productid = @ProductId` would change the left join back to an inner join.

Comment: Yes it would but in the end the clustered index seek will negate it. So overall the performance will be better than the `CASE WHEN EXISTS`.

Comment: This will also bring back duplicates because of the join. The `CASE WHEN EXISTS` is a semi join. Your claim that LOJ can somehow make better use of indexes than a semi join is incorrect in SQL Server.

Comment: Performance is now the main issue with this query, it's returning the correct results but is just slow doing so and may get worse as Table B get's larger.

Comment: I read the OP's query again and mine and after some thinking found out that it actually **won't give the right result** in the first place, even not going into the performance debate that I am happy to have - there's something always to learn from it. So I've decided to delete my answer as it give **no real value**. But I'll leave it here for a while so @MartinSmith and the FullTimeSkeleton can see I acknowledge my mistake.